# Nginx - conflicting server name on 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Can't figure out why **nginx** doesn't redirect `www` urls to `non-www`.

I want all `www` urls to be redirected to `non-www`.

Nginx `error.log` shows these messages:

```
2019/05/28 17:45:07 [warn] 21670#21670: conflicting server name "www.my-first-domain.at" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

**sites-available**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-first-domain.at;
    return 301 $scheme://my-first-domain.at$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-second-domain.at;
    return 301 $scheme://my-second-domain.at$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name my-first-domain.at my-second-domain.at;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/futilestudio/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-first-domain.at/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-first-domain.at/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = my-second-domain.at) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-first-domain.at) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name 178.128.xxx.xxx my-first-domain.at my-second-domain.at;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

non-www domains work correctly. Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT**

```
(venv) futilestudio@Brennholz-2:~/myproject sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.my-first-domain.at" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.my-second-domain.at" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: `sites-available` sounds like you might be on Debian 9 or a related Linux distribution. If that's true, I'll have to ask: what's in `sites-enabled` instead? And what does `sudo nginx -t` say? ([You might want to read this.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-debian-9/))

Comment: @telcoM Yes, it's Ubuntu 18.04. I'm going to check the article. I've added `sudo nginx -t` at the bottom of the question. I can't figure out why is it conflicting...

Comment: @telcoM Sorry I forgot to answer to the first question - there is a simlink of sites-available/myproject - it works - non www urls are good, it's just something with non www urls.